# Laravel get attributes of an object

Tags: php, laravel

I want to access the attributes of this department so that I can fetch the courses which exist in there and pass it to the view I've tried this:
dd($department->id) but is doesn't in the controller that works only in views

```
$department = Student::where('students.id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->join('departments', 'department_id', 'departments.id')
                ->select('departments.id', 'departments.nom')
                ->get();
                //dd($department);
```

Comment: You should try `dd($department->first()->id)` this works. get() returns collection so you need to fetch first element from the collection.

Comment: `$department` is a `Collection`, not a single instance of `Student`. Use `->first()` or a loop.

Comment: Thanks. I love you guys that works ;)